# How to save files to ec2 instance through flask like s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have developed an web app, in which files needs to be uploaded from local PC to AWS EC2 instance via flask web call and run the machine learning model in the back-end. But, could not find any related resources to do that.

Can we upload in AWS S3 instead and link ec2 EBS and S3?

If any help is provided then it will be useful to do this!

Answer (score 1):

Use boto to upload files to s3.
In flash create an endpoint that will take the local file and push it to S3.

````
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):
    """Upload a file to an S3 bucket

    :param file_name: File to upload
    :param bucket: Bucket to upload to
    :param object_name: S3 object name. If not specified then file_name is used
    :return: True if file was uploaded, else False
    """

    # If S3 object_name was not specified, use file_name
    if object_name is None:
        object_name = file_name

    # Upload the file
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return False
    return True ```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html
Read This https://www.javatpoint.com/flask-file-uploading
Upload the file to tmp directory and then upload to S3.
````

Comment: Thanks for your time!@Karandeepdps. I need to upload all files in AWS EC2 EBS via flask call, and found this link useful. (https://github.com/ibrahimokdadov/upload_file_python)

Comment: please accept the answer if it solves your problem.